# Comma or semicolon in this particular case!

Tags: commas, semicolons

The nationalities shall mingle, the nights shall sparkle.

or

The nationalities shall mingle; the nights shall sparkle.

Two complete sentences, right? So, I guess they should be separated by a semicolon to show the connection. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes, a semi-colon would be the minimum. In this case the wording of the two clauses is designed so that one echoes the other, and in my opinion a comma is enough.

Comment: I agree – I'd not consider this a comma splice error either. The progression comma -> semicolon -> two sentences here reflects a purely pragmatic difference as to how much 'pause for thought / staccato emphasis' one wishes to convey.